# Adding a property to each object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am making an app that requires the user to click on a location and then will be directed to the location via Google Maps.The locations are an array of objects. This is what the location files look like.

```
$scope.SiteLocs = [
          {
            "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
            "visibility": "0",
            "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
            "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
            "Point": { "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0" }
          },
          {
            "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
            "visibility": "0",
            "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
            "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
            "Point": { "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0" }
          },
          {
            "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
            "visibility": "0",
            "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
            "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
            "Point": { "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0" }
          }, ect...
```

I want to add another element to every item in the array. 
I tried adding it in through the `.concat()` method but that didn't seem to work.
If I wanted to add `"carrier": "sprint",` to each location how would I do that?

I forgot to add this bit of code. It splits and reorders the coordinates in the files.

```
angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location) {
      var clength = location.Point.coordinates.length;
      if (location.Point.coordinates.substring(clength - 2, clength) === ",0") {
        location.Point.coordinates = location.Point.coordinates.substring(0, clength - 2).split(",");
        Lat = location.Point.coordinates[0]
        Lon = location.Point.coordinates[1]
        Com = ","
        location.Point.coordinates = Lon.concat(Com,Lat)
      }
```

Comment: This is not a "JSON array"! This is a JavaScript array containing JavaScript objects. JSON is a **textual** data exchange format, just like XML, CSV or YAML.

Comment: Gotcha, Sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at `angular.forEach`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Here's the working JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Wqu68/3/

***Relevant code:***

```
function appCtrl($scope, $http){

    $scope.SiteLocs = [
          {
            "name": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
            "visibility": "0",
            "description": "502 Nelson St, Greenville, MS 38701",
            "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
            "Point": { "coordinates": "-91.05636,33.415485,0" }
          },
          {
            "name": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
            "visibility": "0",
            "description": "242 Blackhawk Trace, Galena, IL 61036",
            "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
            "Point": { "coordinates": "-90.319778,42.390862,0" }
          },
          {
            "name": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
            "visibility": "0",
            "description": "3747 Ocean Dr, Vero Beach, FL 32963",
            "styleUrl": "#waypoint",
            "Point": { "coordinates": "-80.358248,27.659094,0" }
          }]

      angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(place) {
          place.carrier = "Sprint";
     });
```

}

Comment: Yeah I have, I forgot to put that in my question. I added in the code in my question.

Comment: Are you trying to modify SiteLocs after it has already been filled with all the prior information? Also, did you have a question about the forEach that you just posted?

Comment: Yeah, Im trying to add "Carrier": "sprint" to each object in SiteLocs. Also, No, I dont have a question on the forEach, I just thought id add it in if it helps.

Comment: Haha, after looking at AngularJS's forEach code, I would say it's way too complicated for this addition. I'd just use aarosil's advice and use a simple for loop or non-angularjs forEach

Comment: Actually I take that back, haha sorry. It's actually pretty simple, I just derped. I posted a working JSFiddle

Comment: Where did you post it?

Comment: Oh, it's in the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do it right there in the loop you already have `angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(location) {...}` just add `location.carrier = "sprint";` in that function.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use lodash or angular. They all similar.

```
**Solution** using Lodash.js

//using forEach to loop each array
_.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(object){

***//adding carrier as property to each object in the array and giving value 'sprint'
// an identifier/variable can take the place of that value***

    object.carrier = 'sprint';
  });

**Solution** using angular.js
//using forEach to loop each array
```

angular.forEach($scope.SiteLocs, function(object){

```
***//adding carrier as property to each object in the array and giving value 'sprint'
// an identifier/variable can take the place of that value***

    object.carrier = 'sprint';
  });
```